# XamlParseException when building in Release with DataGrid

Tags: datagrid, avaloniaui, avalonia

When trying to build Avalonia application in release configuration it crashes with "XamlParseException when building in Release with DataGrid". In debug mode works perfectly

Adding Avalonia.Controls.DataGrid nuget package directly solves problem, but seems a little bit strange

Answer (score 1):

After some search i found a solution:
In cproj file after:

```
    <!--Condition below is needed to remove Avalonia.Diagnostics package from build output in Release configuration.-->
    <PackageReference Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" Include="Avalonia.Diagnostics" Version="0.10.18" />
```

Just add the line:

````
      <PackageReference Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'" Include="Avalonia.Controls.DataGrid" Version="0.10.18" />```
````

Comment: I think it would be even better to remove the condition and just change it to:
<PackageReference Include="Avalonia.Diagnostics" Version="11.0.2" />